# MySQL count join with binary field

Tags: mysql, join, binary

I'm trying to match data from a table with a count from another table, but i'm having some trouble with this.

My table structure is like this:

tbl_files:

```
id|hash|title|desc
```

tbl_list:

```
id|hex_hash|user
```

hex_hash is binary

My current query looks like this, and it's selecting only one entry instead of the whole table as i'm trying to do.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as count
FROM tbl_files a, tbl_list b
WHERE BINARY HEX(`b`.`hex_hash`) = `a`.`hash`
```

Basically, i want to select * from tbl_files and add the count of matching hash from both tables to the final array like this:

```
    id|hash|title|desc|COUNT
```

Hope someone can help with this, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as count
FROM tbl_files a, tbl_list b
WHERE BINARY HEX(`b`.`hex_hash`) = `a`.`hash`
group by id
```

Comment: Wow, that's a dumb mistake, working now, thanks alots !

Comment: How could i add another count from the same table but with another condition ?

Comment: @JohnKonolol use a case statement `sum(case when condition then 1 else 0 end) as SumOfCondition`  so when true 1 will be returned and added to the sum.  if not true then 0 is added which will not effect the sum.

Comment: That's not what i meant, sorry, the current count is like this:
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as count
FROM tbl_files a, tbl_list b
WHERE BINARY HEX(`b`.`hex_hash`) = `a`.`hash` AND state=1
group by id


And i want to add a field for state=0